# Replace the first and last occurence of a word IF

Tags: php, regex

With this peace of code i replace the first and the last occurence of a word in string.

```
    $text = 'A United States aircraft fly in United States in the United States area.';
    $find = 'United States';
    $replace = ' U.S ';

    $firsto =  preg_replace("/$find/", "$replace", $text, 1); // stolen in stackoverflow 

    $lasto = preg_replace(strrev("/$find/"),strrev($replace),strrev($firsto),1); // stolen in stackoverflow 

    $final = strrev($lasto);

    echo "<br><br> $final";
```

In this example there are 3 occurrences of the word `United States` and the code below replace the first and the last occurrence.

```
   And Output: A U.S aircraft fly in United States in the U.S area.
```

my problem is that `if` the occurrence of `word = 2` like this:

```
         $text = 'A United States aircraft fly in United States';
```

Using a modified version of the code above `i want to replace only the first occurrence if there are only 2 occurrences` and output something like this.

```
     Output: A U.S aircraft fly in United States.
```

else `if occurrence > 2` use the code below. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$firsto =  preg_replace("/$find/", "$replace", $text, 1); // outputs '123def abcdef abcdef'

$final = $firsto;
$m;
if(preg_match_all("/($find)/",$firsto, $m) && count($m[1]) > 1){
    $lasto = preg_replace(strrev("/$find/"),strrev($replace),strrev($firsto),1);
    $final = strrev($lasto);
}
```

Comment: $m is the variable at where the all matched groups are stored by the preg_match_all function. I have used it inside the if() condition to check the count. If I do not declare this $m above the condition, the count() will not recognize the variable $m.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (substr_count($text,$find) == 2){
    $firsto =  preg_replace("/$find/", "$replace", $text, 1);
}
else{
    ... use existing
}
```